# Unopened cheese shipped in heat

Tags: cheese

I accidentally left an unopened block of Monterray Jack at my Mom's house (about 4-1/2 hours away) and she shipped it back to me (1-day air, no less) in a box without anything to keep it cool and the temp today is 84 degrees F.  It's all soft and floppy now, but not at all sweaty.  Would you consider that still edible?  I saw a previous question concerning cheese left out in a car overnight, while cool, but this is slightly different circumstances.

Comment: Yoru mom paid to 1 day a block of Monterray Jack cheese?  Was the cheese refrigerated when you bought it?  If yes then don't eat the cheese.  Even if it was not refrigerated when you bought it then I would not eat it.

Comment: If the block was unopened, I would probably use it - it is sealed, I have rarely seen plastic sealed foods go bad that quickly, and cheese is aged at warmer temps than refrigerated.  But I don't mind potential risks, so take as you will.  As for soft and floppy, that has to do with temperature more than anything else - I would certainly use it for melting purposes, but even if chilled the texture might not settle back to the same as if it had been refrigerated if that is important to you.  Then again, if it wasn't sweating - it might, you can try chilling it and see if it works.

Comment: What were the temperatures it was out in?

Comment: Paparazzi, Megha, elias altenberg & bigsandwich - Sorry for the delayed response. I never got any email notifications. I left some clothing items behind, besides the cheese. Somehow my mom didn't think mid 80's temps would be too hot if it got there the next day.  Her mind sometimes works in mysterious ways...  Yes, it was refrigerated when I purchased it and again after being shipped, but then I threw it out, thought better of it a couple of hours later, washed off the package and re-refrigerated it.  It never did sweat and it now looks and feels the same as it did when I first purchased it.

Answer (score 1):

If it hasn't sweated and doesn't have any mold spots on it you should be fine to eat it. Putting it in the fridge for a bit should firm it back up to the consistency you're used to.

Comment: I finally opened the package and it was kinda slimy, so it made it's final trip to the garbage.  Fortunately, I'd picked up an additional block beforehand...just in case.  Thanks for your feedback!